# error C2059: syntax error :"->" and ";"

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When trying to compile this program, I got these errors:

```
1>e:\workspace_for_c\02-3\02-3\02-3\02-3.cpp(83): error C2059: syntax       error:“new”
1>e:\workspace_for_c\02-3\02-3\02-3\02-3.cpp(84): error C2059: syntax error:“->”
1>e:\workspace_for_c\02-3\02-3\02-3\02-3.cpp(89): error C2059: syntax error:“;”
1>e:\workspace_for_c\02-3\02-3\02-3\02-3.cpp(90): error C2059: syntax error:“->”
1>e:\workspace_for_c\02-3\02-3\02-3\02-3.cpp(105): error C2059: syntax error:“;”
```

My code:

[image]

[image]

Note:I am using Windows 7 with VS 2010

Comment: Please post actual code as inline text in your question, *not* as links to images on an external site.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have some C code but you're trying to compile it as if it were C++, in which language `new` is a reserved word. Change the suffix from .cpp to .c and the use of `new` should not then cause a problem (although it's generally a bad idea to use keywords from common programming languages as variable names).

Comment: I rename the variable from "new" to "newList".The error gone! Thanks~

Comment: Yes, that's good, and if you are using C rather than C++ then change the file name suffix from .cpp to .c, otherwise you may run into other problems like this. (The .cpp suffix is for C++ source files, you need to use .c for C source files.)

Comment: @Tommy Congratulations, you just "cured" the fever by breaking your thermometer. Change your goddamned file extension instead of continuing to compile your C code as C++!

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention on the syntax coloring, VisualStudio is suggesting you that "new" is different from other variables names. Because it is a .CPP source, it is a reserved keyword.